# navigationBar isn't showing when I put a UINavigationController in a UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller

I'm adding a UIViewController to a UINavigationController and then setting a UIPopoverController's view to the UINavigationController. Everything is working great except that I don't get a navigationBar at the top of the popoverController. I'm creating everything like this:

```
QueryViewController *puvc = [[QueryViewController alloc] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] autorelease];
[nc pushViewController:puvc animated:YES];

self.popUp = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:nc] autorelease];
[self.popUp presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[self.toolbarItems objectAtIndex:0] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
self.popUp.delegate = self;
```

I've tried to set navigationBarHidden = NO and it still doesn't show up. I have this code in my viewDidLoad of my QueryViewController:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(500.0, 500.0);
self.title = @"Queries";
```

Is there something that I'm missing to display the navigationBar? I am already in a UINavigationController for my main screen, could this be part of my problem?

Comment: hey i have also deal with similar kind of issue. i have created custom view nib, with date picker and navigation bar(with done button). But when i ran app on iOS 5 it ran correctly, but in ios 4.3, navigationbar was getting displayed but no bar item button available. It was really strange for me..

Comment: Anybody has faced such issue. The same code/nib ran fine for iOS 5 so what else to do.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 QueryViewController *puvc = [[QueryViewController alloc] autorelease];
 UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] autorelease];
```

Maybe your code is wrong. Where is `init` methods?

You have to init both your `QueryViewController` and `UINavigationController`. For the second use `initWithRootViewController` method.

```
QueryViewController *puvc = [[[QueryViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *nc = [[[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:pucv] autorelease];
//[nc pushViewController:puvc animated:YES];
```

If you use `initWithRootViewController` it's not necessary to push puvc instance.

You could try also this (I like to release memory explicity, not using autorelease).

```
QueryViewController *puvc = [[QueryViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:pucv];
//[nc pushViewController:puvc animated:YES];
```

Then at the end of your code snippet remember to release `puvc` and `nc`.

```
[puvc release];
[nc release];
```

**P.S.** Check the code because I've written without XCode.

Comment: Using initWithRootViewController and removing pushViewController works, thanks for your help!